# VC++, mutex, but duplicate execution

Tags: visual-c++, mutex

project have the two applications.

1. windows normal program
2. windows service program

Service program runs the normal program. but sometimes normal program has duplication execution.. SYSTEM account and USERS account two things..
This source code I used, and it works on all versions of Windows.

```
 auto const MutexName = L"Global\\Test_SingleInstance";

    if (NULL == ::OpenMutex
        ( MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS
        , FALSE
        , MutexName))
    {
        duplicationPreventor = ::CreateMutex
            ( NULL
            , FALSE
            , MutexName
            );

        if (NULL == duplicationPreventor)
        {
            Log("Could not guarantee single instance.");
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Log("There is existing instance.");
        return false;
    }
```

Why does this problem appear?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition, or to be precise, [Time of check to time of use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) problem. If two instances run this code nearly simultaneously, then both will get `NULL` from `OpenMutex`, and then both will succeed with `CreateMutex`.

The right way to do this is to call `CreateMutex` straight away, then call `GetLastError` to check for `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`.